# can't install windows 8.1 after Ubuntu install

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, windows-8.1, ubuntu-12.04

I have lenovo G510 laptop. Initially it was running on Win 8.1, I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside it. after installation I couldn't boot my Win8.1 (I choose it, after one second it return me to the select screen again!).

I have tried solution [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm) but with no response. Then I see a comment about load UEFI default settings. then I reload it to be `Support Legacy - Boot Legacy First`
At this point every thing hanged !
The select screen has gone, trying to install win 8.1 on another drive (Primary) fails (it start the setup and after the first reboot at the setup it doesn't boot win 8.1 and hang - although booting from the DVD is still working)

Any solution that can help without affecting my data nor the previous win 8.1 drive.

---

Drive Information: **MBR**

Partition 1: 350MB - System reserved
Partition 2: 80GB - 50GB free - primary (original win 8.1)
Partition 3: 365GB - 242GB free - primary (data)
Partition 4: 20GB - primary (the second win8.1 installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the boot "Partition 1: 350MB - System reserved" partition

I just formatted this partition and reinstalled windows 8.1 on the "second partition". The setup detected the old installation and added it to the boot menu.

Later I installed Ubuntu on the second partition and rebuilt the BCD using the attached link above.